# Find Class Unique ID

Tags: c#, installation, registry, identity, uniqueidentifier

When I install a program, a registry entry is created for a class under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`.
The entry name is a long string consists of characters and numbers.

I have to create such a registry entry programmatically, how can I get this unique ID that represents the class in the registry?

Answer (score 1):

Easy as this:

```
Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
```

See [System.Guid.NewGuid()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.guid.newguid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. Is it the same guid that the system gives to this class in case of installation?